How to link the user id of Phone authentication with user id of email password authentication in Firebase (Android Studio)
I am a beginner in Android development and am making a pretty simple Login-Signup app that first logs in the users with email and password and then goes on to Phone authentication to verify their phone number via OTP. Now I found that Firebase provides different user IDs for Email/password authentication and Phone authentication. But I need them both to be under one userid so that they can log in to their account through email or phone number.
I did read various answers and official Firebase documentation on how to link multiple auth providers using linkWithCredential and tried to implement it in my code but it always fails showing error that this email is already in use by another account.
I couldn't follow where I need to place the linkWithCredential method.
Please guide me, I am attaching the code for the two activities.
1)LoginActivity
package com.example.bccl

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.text.InputType
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import com.example.bccl.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthOptions
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val binding: ActivityLoginBinding by lazy {
        ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private var passwordShowing = false
    private val db = Firebase.firestore

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        currentUser?.let {
            Log.d(TAG,"user id is ${currentUser.uid}")
            db.collection("user").document(currentUser.uid)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    if (it != null && it.data?.get("otpverified") == true) {
                        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    }
                }



        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(binding.root)

        auth = Firebase.auth

        binding.eyepassword2.setOnClickListener {
            passwordShowing = !passwordShowing

            if (passwordShowing) {
                binding.editTextTextPassword.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
                binding.eyepassword2.setImageResource(R.drawable.eye)
            } else {
                binding.editTextTextPassword.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
                binding.eyepassword2.setImageResource(R.drawable.eye_off)
            }
            binding.editTextTextPassword.setSelection(binding.editTextTextPassword.text.length)
        }

        binding.SignUpText.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, SignUp::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        if (currentUser != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"user id is ${currentUser.uid}")
        }

        binding.loginbutton.setOnClickListener {
            val email = binding.editTextTextEmailAddress.text.toString().trim()
            val password = binding.editTextTextPassword.text.toString().trim()

            if (email.isBlank() || password.isBlank()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Fill In All The Details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter a Valid Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.loginbutton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                binding.loginbutton.isEnabled = false

                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.loginbutton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        binding.loginbutton.isEnabled = true

                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success")
                            val intent = Intent(this, OTPVerificationActivity::class.java)

                            val userId = auth.currentUser?.uid
                            userId?.let {
                                val ref = db.collection("user").document(it)
                                ref.get()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                                        if (document != null) {
                                            val phoneNumber = document.data?.get("phone").toString()

                                            val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
                                                .setPhoneNumber("+91$phoneNumber")
                                                .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                .setActivity(this)
                                                .setCallbacks(object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                                                    override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                                                        // Handle verification completion
                                                    }

                                                    override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                            this@LoginActivity,
                                                            e.message,
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                                        ).show()
                                                    }

                                                    override fun onCodeSent(
                                                        verificationId: String,
                                                        token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
                                                    ) {
                                                        intent.putExtra("verificationId", verificationId)
                                                        startActivity(intent)
                                                        finish()
                                                    }

                                                    override fun onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(verificationId: String) {
                                                        // Handle code auto-retrieval timeout
                                                    }
                                                })
                                                .build()

                                            PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Invalid Credentials.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }
}


OTPVerification Activity

package com.example.bccl

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import com.example.bccl.databinding.ActivityOtpverificationBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class OTPVerificationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val binding: ActivityOtpverificationBinding by lazy {
        ActivityOtpverificationBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    private val db = Firebase.firestore
    private val auth = Firebase.auth
    private var realuser: String? = null
    private var hero : String? = null

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.d(TAG,"onStart() method")
        hero = auth.currentUser?.uid
        if (hero != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User ID :$hero")
        }

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(binding.root)

        fetchPhoneNumber()

        val otpbackend = intent.getStringExtra("verificationId")

        binding.verifybutton.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d(TAG,"User ID :" + auth.currentUser?.uid)
            realuser= auth.currentUser?.uid
            verifyOtp(otpbackend)
        }

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        setupOtpInputs()
    }

    private fun fetchPhoneNumber() {
        val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
        userId?.let { uid ->
            val ref = db.collection("user").document(uid)
            ref.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    it?.data?.get("phone")?.toString()?.let { phoneNumber ->
                        binding.phnnumber.text = String.format("+91-%s", phoneNumber)
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Phone Number Fetched Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        Log.d("Firebase", "DocumentSnapshot data: ${it.data}")
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.e("Firebase", "Error fetching phone number", exception)
                }
        }
    }

    private fun verifyOtp(otpbackend: String?) {
        val otp = binding.editTextText1.text.toString() +
                binding.editTextText2.text.toString() +
                binding.editTextText3.text.toString() +
                binding.editTextText4.text.toString() +
                binding.editTextText5.text.toString() +
                binding.editTextText6.text.toString()

        if (otp.length != 6) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        if (otpbackend == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.verifybutton.visibility = View.GONE

        val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(otpbackend, otp)

        auth.currentUser?.let { currentUser ->
            currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.verifybutton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success")

                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                        if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid OTP.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Log-in failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }

                }

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }
    }

    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.verifybutton.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                if (task.isSuccessful) {


                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success,  user id : ${auth.currentUser?.uid}")

                                val currentUser = auth.currentUser

                    if (currentUser != null) {
                        markOTPVerification(currentUser.uid)
                    }

                                    // Proceed to main activity
                                    navigateToMainActivity()



                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid OTP.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Log-in failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    private fun navigateToMainActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    private fun markOTPVerification(uid: String) {
        db.collection("user").document(uid)
            .update("otpverified", true)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "OTP Verification marked in database successfully")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Error marking OTP Verification", e)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to mark OTP Verification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }

    private fun setupOtpInputs() {
        val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if (s?.length == 1) {
                    when (currentFocus?.id) {
                        R.id.editTextText1 -> binding.editTextText2.requestFocus()
                        R.id.editTextText2 -> binding.editTextText3.requestFocus()
                        R.id.editTextText3 -> binding.editTextText4.requestFocus()
                        R.id.editTextText4 -> binding.editTextText5.requestFocus()
                        R.id.editTextText5 -> binding.editTextText6.requestFocus()
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
        }

        binding.editTextText1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        binding.editTextText2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        binding.editTextText3.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        binding.editTextText4.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        binding.editTextText5.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        binding.editTextText6.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
    }
}




Now I found that Firebase provides different user IDs for Email/password authentication and Phone authentication.

Yes, that's the expected behavior, to have two different UIDs when using two different types of authentication, when using signInWithEmailAndPassword().

But I need them both to be under one userid so that they can log in to their account through email or phone number. I did read various answers and official Firebase documentation on how to link multiple auth providers using linkWithCredential.

Yes, you can link multiple Auth providers. According to the official documentation:

You can allow users to sign in to your app using multiple authentication providers by linking auth provider credentials to an existing user account. Users are identifiable by the same Firebase user ID regardless of the authentication provider they used to sign in. For example, a user who signed in with a password can link a Google account and sign in with either method in the future.

So in your particular use case, you have to link the phone auth provider to the FirebaseUser object after the Firebase Authentication with email and password is complete. More info below:

How to link Phone with Email and Password Authentication in Firebase?


Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Thanks a lot for your answer. It did guide me in the right direction and finally what worked for me was first unlinking the phone number with its user id and then linking it to the user id of email-password authentication.

I am having a new problem now , the whole thing works completely well for the test phone numbers and they get linked as expected. But for real phone numbers when I enter the OTP code it gives the error The SMS code has expired. I've read answers relating to auto retrieval and auto verification of code  by Android but didn't help much. Can you help me with this?

It's good to hear that you made it work. The second comment sounds like a new issue that basically should be considered another question, so I recommend you post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own MCVE, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.
